# Edges don't "stick" to Object in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode, edges

[image: they don't stick]

Whenever I enter edit mode, these lines supposedly are the edges to edit. But they look to be very squared and detached instead of sticking on the object. Why is this happening?

Comment: You seem to be using NURBS objects

Comment: What you have here is called a "nurbs" (Non-Uniform Rational Basis Splines). This is a special type of mesh described (say) by some kind of contour line (the one in orange in the image). So this is an expected behavior. What you seem to expect is from standard meshes that can be add (and modified later) by Add/Mesh/the object you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a surface object, and this is the way surface objects behave. If you want the edges to "stick to the torus" as you say, you will need to convert to mesh (press alt-c and select the second option). You could also simply initially add a mesh torus and use that.